# Honda Clarity 2018 Non-Touring PHEV: how to simulate nav keys to call `systemdiag`?

Tags: adb, 4.2-jelly-bean, input-methods, keyboard-shortcuts, automotive-head-unit

I have a damaged head unit that no longer responds to touch.  I've managed to get access to ADB (I have root and USB debugging was enabled), but the problem now are the touch keys along the side of the unit.  The VOL+ and VOL- keys appear to work just like Android's (e.g., booting into safe-mode by holding the key down still works), and the menu and home keys also appear to work the same as they do in native Android.  My problem now is two-fold:

1. What Android key events would be the equivalent to the Audio (Power) key and Brightness Level toggle key?
2. How can I simulate `Audio`+`Menu`+`Brightness` to call `systemdiag`?  Will simulated touches (they are outside of rendered screen bounds?) or `send key` events even work?  Or is there another way to programmatically call the diagnostics screen directly?