# Access Diagnostic Screen Programmatically

Tags: diagnostics

How do I access the `diag` screen programmatically on a Honda Clarity 2018 PHEV non-touring (with root)?

Clarity's has a damaged HMU (touch digitizer not functioning).  I have root on the unit, and USB/wireless debugging is enabled, so I am still able to operate the head unit (through ADB shell, or somewhat through the frontend by sending emulated `input keyevent` or other key events).

However, this leaves the touch keys on the side of the screen inoperable, as they are not (to my inference, thus far) considered virtual navigation keys, but rather appear to be additional hardware input device keys.  I've checked the listed key codes within `system/usr/keychars` and `system/usr/keymaps`, but sending these through ADB doesn't appear to do anything.  Furthermore, even if I am able to find the correct input keyevent codes, I'm not certain it will be possible to invoke the <kbd>Audio</kbd>+<kbd>Menu</kbd>+<kbd>Brightness</kbd> keys together, and whether doing so would work to invoke the diag menu?

I've also thought to directly call `systemdiag` through `adb shell start`, but none of the activity URI's enumerated via `systemdump` appear to be accepted, and all result in component name errors.  I'm sure this should also be possible, but I'm not sure whether I'm committing a syntactical error or just using the incorrect activities altogether.

Comment: ADB stands for Android Debug Bridge. This is really more related to Android than auto mechanics, I suggest this gets migrated to the Android.SE. It will get far better answers there.

Comment: @GdD Well, for one thing, I'd already posted [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252028/honda-clarity-2018-non-touring-phev-how-to-simulate-nav-keys-to-call-systemdia) in Android SE to that regard, which had all of 18 views and 0 answers.  And for another, I don't believe this question to be more relevant to the Android community than it is to the autotech one, much in the same way that WSL questions are a better fit in SU than they would be in the Unix/Linux communities.